# how to cancel a particular scheduled notification and schedule a new notification when the time is set in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a tableview where i am displaying my scheduled notifications in tableview .In the navigation bar of the tableview there are 2 buttons edit and add button.On clicking the edit button the tableview changes to edit mode such that users can edit there notifications which are already scheduled.On clicking the add button the user can schedule new notification.I have done which schedule notification.My problem is with editing a notification i.e if there is a notification to be ring on 2.00 PM and i am editing this notification to 2.30 PM, the notification gets edited to 2.30 PM but the problem is instead of displaying the edited notification of 2.30 PM ,it displays both the notification i.e of 2.00 PM and 2.30 PM.Please help me in solving this problem.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cancel a local notification you need to tell your application's shared instance of UIApplication to cancel that particular local notification.

It looks something like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theLocalNotificationThatYouWantToCancel];
```

You will probably also need to find the instance of UILocalNotification that you want to cancel.  You can do this by getting a list of all scheduled notifications from UIApplication and then iterating through them until you find the one with the fireDate that matches the one you want to cancel.

You can grab all the scheduled notifications like this:

```
NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: i am getting confused.Can u help me on how to iterate through the notifications array until it matches with the firedate that i want to cancel.